# PwExpChk.vbs can I add a company logo?

Tags: vbscript, graphical-logo

The script I want to use in my environment is stated below, it is a .vbs script. I was wondering if it is possible to add a company logo to the pop-up box? If it is possible how would I do it? Also added is a picture (screen shot) of the results of the script as is... The script works great, I just need to know about the logo part. Due note that the logo will be a simple .jpg file and I am hoping I can add the company logo above the popup box instead of imbedded, something like:

Company logo

msgbox

[Results of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMArw.png)

```
    '==========================================
 ' Check for password expiring notification
 '==========================================
 ' First, get the domain policy.
 '==========================================
 Dim oDomain
 Dim oUser
 Dim maxPwdAge
 Dim numDays
 Dim warningDays

warningDays = 14

 Set LoginInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")  
 Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & LoginInfo.UserName & "")  
 strDomainDN = UCase(LoginInfo.DomainDNSName) 
 strUserDN = LoginInfo.UserName

'========================================
 ' Check if password is non-expiring.
 '========================================
 Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
 intUserAccountControl = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
 If intUserAccountControl And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
     'WScript.Echo "The password does not expire."
 Else

     Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
     Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")

    '========================================
     ' Calculate the number of days that are
     ' held in this value.
     '========================================
     numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + _
                     maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
     'WScript.Echo "Maximum Password Age: " & numDays

     '========================================
     ' Determine the last time that the user
     ' changed his or her password.
     '========================================
     Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)

    '========================================
     ' Add the number of days to the last time
     ' the password was set.
     '========================================
     whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
     fromDate = Date
     daysLeft = DateDiff("d",fromDate,whenPasswordExpires)

     'WScript.Echo "Password Last Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged

    if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
         Msgbox "Password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires & chr(13) & chr(13) & "Once logged in, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and" & chr(13) & "select the 'Change a password' option", 0, " PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!"
     End if

End if

'========================================
 ' Clean up.
 '========================================
 Set oUser = Nothing
 Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
 Set oDomain = Nothing
```

Comment: It is not possible to add an image without significant changes here. Msgbox supports strings only.

Comment: Put your script into an HTA. An HTA is a renamed HTML file that allows web pages to act like programs. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I based this on [mockmyberet/ChooseFile.vbs](https://gist.github.com/mockmyberet/2638448)

```
Sub PasswordExpirationDialog(daysLeft, whenPasswordExpires)
    Dim fso, objShell,  HTAFileName, HtaFile
    Const TemporaryFolder = 2
    Const ForReading = 1

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
    HTAFileName = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder).Path & "\PasswordExpirationDialog.hta"
    Set HtaFile = fso.CreateTextFile(HTAFileName, True)
    With HtaFile
        .writeline("<html><head>")
        .writeline("<title>PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!</title>")
        .writeline("<HTA:APPLICATION ID='PaswordDialog'/></head><script language='VBScript'>")

        .writeline("Sub Window_OnLoad")
        .writeline("window.resizeto 700,400")
        .writeline("End Sub")

        .writeline("</script><body bgcolor='white'>")
        .writeline("<image src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/New_Orleans_Saints.svg/1000px-New_Orleans_Saints.svg.png' width='72' height='72' />")
        .writeline("<h1>")
        .writeline("Password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires)
        .writeline("<br><br>Once logged in, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and")
        .writeline("<br>select the 'Change a password' option")

        .writeline("<center><button onclick='Self.Close'>Okay</button></center>")
        .writeline("</h1></body></html>")
        .Close
    End With
    Set HtaFile = Nothing

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "%windir%\SysWoW64\mshta.exe " & Chr(34) & HTAFileName & Chr(34)

    WScript.Sleep 500
    fso.DeleteFile HTAFileName, True
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Usage

```
PasswordExpirationDialog 4, Date+ 4
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, some questions though:

Will this script run as is or do I need to merge it with my orginal .vbs script?
The PasswordExpirationDialog 4, Date+ 4 part, I do not see that in your script here do I need to add it?
Instead of referencing a http address can I reference the netlogon share for the logo.gif?

Comment: Or do I plug in the sub part where the msgbox is?
Forgive my stupidity, I can modify and customize but I do not have the experience writing from scratch with .vbs and this is a first for me getting involved with .hta I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: I modified it to run as.  If you are deploying to any 32 bit systems we'll need to modify it to use MSHta in Program Files 86.

Comment: So I should beable to run as:

cscript "c:\passwordexpiration.vbs"

Comment: Yes, it ran fine for me under cScript.  Do you use [VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/)?  You can download it for free.  It has a ton of example codes and HTAEdit come with it.

Comment: I ran it with cscript and it did not error out but it did not show the pop-up box either.

Comment: Comment out `fso.DeleteFile HTAFileName, True`.  I was having a problem of fso deleting the file before mshta opened it.

Comment: Microsoft is trying to phase out HTA.  I am not sure if it will work on Windows 10.  There are also phasing out IE, so writing a temp webpage is not an option.  Can you run a power shell script in your environment?

Comment: Yes I can run powershell in our enviroment

Comment: You can use Powershell to check for password expiration.  PowerShell can then create a win form with whatever you want on it. You could probably set Group Policy up to run the PowerShell script when the users log in.  I was looking at modifying this:[Password Expiry Email Notification](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Password-Expiry-Email-177c3e27).  But I won't be able to get to it till next week.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to research it.

Comment: I did start a new thread with this information:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252574/password-expiration-notification-vbscript

Comment: Would it be better all around to use the script in the link below?

https://www.reddit.com/r/usefulscripts/comments/4dc7pk/htavbscript_password_expiration_notification/?st=iqln4iie&sh=f54b02e2

Comment: I can generate the window but on my test machine I can not get it to read the password policy meaning it always pops up at logon.  what am I missing?