# Password Expiration notification vbscript

Tags: vbscript, passwords

I got great help from the link below, I have made a few changes but I can not get it to work, any thoughts? What it is supposed to do is go get the domain policy and check the password expiration information, if it is within the 14 day time frame it shows a popup (it works if I use msgbox) I want to use a company logo with the text, this is the problem area.

[PwExpChk.vbs can I add a company logo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231682/pwexpchk-vbs-can-i-add-a-company-logo)

```
'==========================================
 ' Check for password expiring notification
 '==========================================
 ' First, get the domain policy.
 '==========================================
 Dim oDomain
 Dim oUser
 Dim maxPwdAge
 Dim numDays
 Dim warningDays

warningDays = 14

 Set LoginInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")  
 Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & LoginInfo.UserName &)  
 strDomainDN = UCase(LoginInfo.DomainDNSName) 
 strUserDN = LoginInfo.UserName

'========================================
 ' Check if password is non-expiring.
 '========================================
 Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
 intUserAccountControl = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
 If intUserAccountControl And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
     'WScript.Echo "The password does not expire."
 Else

     Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
     Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")

    '========================================
     ' Calculate the number of days that are
     ' held in this value.
     '========================================
     numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + _
                     maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
     'WScript.Echo "Maximum Password Age: " & numDays

     '========================================
     ' Determine the last time that the user
     ' changed his or her password.
     '========================================
     Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)

    '========================================
     ' Add the number of days to the last time
     ' the password was set.
     '========================================
     whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
     fromDate = Date
     daysLeft = DateDiff("d",fromDate,whenPasswordExpires)

     'WScript.Echo "Password Last Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged

    if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
         Sub PasswordExpirationDialog(daysLeft, whenPasswordExpires)
Dim fso, objShell,  HTAFileName, HtaFile
Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Const ForReading = 1

Sub PasswordExpirationDialog(daysLeft, whenPasswordExpires)
Dim fso, objShell,  HTAFileName, HtaFile
Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Const ForReading = 1

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
HTAFileName = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder).Path & "c:\windows\temp\PasswordExpirationDialog.hta"
Set HtaFile = fso.CreateTextFile(HTAFileName, True)
With HtaFile
    .writeline("<html><head>")
    .writeline("<title>PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!</title>")
    .writeline("<HTA:APPLICATION ID='PaswordDialog'/></head><script language='VBScript'>")

    .writeline("Sub Window_OnLoad")
    .writeline("window.resizeto 700,400")
    .writeline("End Sub")

    .writeline("</script><body bgcolor='white'>")
    .writeline("<image src='\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\Logo2.jpg' width='448' height='170' /><br>")
    .writeline("<h2>")
    .writeline("Password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires)
    .writeline("<br><br>Once logged in, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and")
    .writeline("<br>select the 'Change a password' option<br><br>")

    .writeline("<center><button onclick='Self.Close'>Click_To_Close</button></center>")
    .writeline("</h2></body></html>")
    .Close
End With
Set HtaFile = Nothing

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%windir%\System32\mshta.exe " & Chr(34) & HTAFileName & Chr(34)

WScript.Sleep 500
fso.DeleteFile HTAFileName, True
Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
     End if

End if

'========================================
 ' Clean up.
 '========================================
 Set oUser = Nothing
 Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
 Set oDomain = Nothing
```

Comment: Perhaps you can fix the formatting it'd be easier to give a reply.

Comment: Fixed as requested

Comment: Would it be better all around to use the script in the link below?

https://www.reddit.com/r/usefulscripts/comments/4dc7pk/htavbscript_password_expiration_notification/?st=iqln4iie&sh=f54b02e2