# vbscript statement mismatch string failing

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am running the script listed in the link below.

[PwExpChk.vbs can I add a company logo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231682/pwexpchk-vbs-can-i-add-a-company-logo)

I have substituted the Msgbox with the following:

```
if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
     strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" -13
     Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
     RC = WshShell.run(strCMD , 0, False)

 End if
```

It is failing at:

```
 strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" -13
```

I ran the command using the mshta.exe manually and it ran successfully. If I remove the -13 it runs successfully.

The error that generates is `"Type mismatch: '[string "\\domain\netlogon\"]'` ... the -13 needs to be there, Any help would be great

**EDIT Add code from below**

I tried the one below and it calls the hta file... now the hta file errors out.

```
if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
   strCMD = "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" & " -" & intDaysRemaining 
  Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
  RC = WshShell.run(strCMD , 0, False)  
End if
```

Comment: Put it inside the double quotes and add a space after .hta

Comment: so make it like:
    strCMD = ""\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" -13"

Comment: That's wrong - what is -13? is it a parameter?

Comment: The hta file has a calculation inside it, thus the reason for the -13

Comment: So did you try the  edit below? And add an edit above to your code to what you're using now that doesn't work

Comment: I did and it failed, I posted both scripts and more detail in the link below, it should help visualize what I am trying to do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403626/vbscript-hta-file-password-notification

Comment: Don't create duplicate questions

Comment: Closing this question since the duplicate has more complete code. Please do not re-post questions. If you need to provide additional information: edit your current question.

Answer (score 0):

This will take care of your syntax error

Change the offending line to

```
strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta -13"
```

EDIT - if you NEED the quotes in there, then use double quoting

```
strCMD =  """\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta""" & " -13"
```

vbscript was thinking you wanted to subtract 13 from a string

Comment: I ran it like that and it did not work, even when I manually ran it

Comment: It's not going to run manually - so don't try it that way. You said you wanted it to run from your script - copy/paste my code - or update yours to show EXACTLY what you're using

Comment: I tried that and it did not work, I tried the one below and it calls the hta file... now the hta file errors out.

            if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
             strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" & " -" & intDaysRemaining 
             Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
             RC = WshShell.run(strCMD , 0, False)

         End if

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print strCMD` after you set its value, before you call it - and copy/paste those results to your question. Then copy image of you manually calling it from the command line successfully. Then copy/paste results of Debug.Print result to the command line and show the result