# Password notification script raising "type mismatch" error for remaining number of days

Tags: vbscript, passwords, hta

I can get each one to work by themselves but I can not get them to work together, the logon script uses the `strArg =` to call on the HTA file, the HTA file generates a password window. When the logon script runs the HTA file errors out on lines 31 and 106.

I know the issue lies within the `strArg`, I can not figure it out. It should be notifying endusers at the 13 days before expiring mark. Any help would be great. Currently, as the script is now, I get an error with the HTA file part:

> Line: 31 and 106
>   Error: Type Mismatch 'strARG'
>   code: 0

I did open the question in the link below but those suggestions did not solve the problem.

[vbscript statement mismatch sring failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386289/vbscript-statement-mismatch-sring-failing)

```vb
Dim oDomain
Dim oUser
Dim maxPwdAge
Dim numDays
Dim warningDays

warningDays = 13

Set LoginInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")  
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & LoginInfo.UserName & "")  
strDomainDN = UCase(LoginInfo.DomainDNSName) 
strUserDN = LoginInfo.UserName

Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
intUserAccountControl = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
If intUserAccountControl And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
  'WScript.Echo "The password does not expire."
Else
  Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
  Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")

  ' Calculate the number of days that are held in this value.
  numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + _
                  maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
  'WScript.Echo "Maximum Password Age: " & numDays

  Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)

  whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
  fromDate = Date
  daysLeft = DateDiff("d", fromDate, whenPasswordExpires)

  'WScript.Echo "Password Last Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged

  If (daysLeft < warningDays) And (daysLeft > -1) Then
    strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" & " -" & intDaysRemaining 
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    RC = WshShell.Run(strCMD , 0, False)
  End If
End If

Set oUser = Nothing
Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
Set oDomain = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

The HTA file:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Password Reminder</title>
<hta:application
  border="thin
  borderstyle="normal"
  caption="Password Reminder"
  contextmenu="yes"
  maximizebutton="Yes"
  minimizebutton="no"
  navigable="yes"
  scroll="no"
  selection="yes"
  showintaskbar="yes"
  singleinstance="yes"
  sysmenu="Yes"
  WINDOWSTATE="normal"
  id="objPasswordHTA">

<script language="vbscript">
Sub Window_onLoad
  strArg = 13

  arrCommands = Split(objPasswordHTA.commandLine, "-")
  If UBound(arrCommands) > 0 Then
    strArg = arrCommands(UBound(arrCommands))
  End If

  'setup the window size depending on how many days remain
  strArg = strArg * 1
  If strArg <= 5 Then
    self.MoveTo 200,50
    window.ResizeTo 1000,850

    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshShell.AppActivate "Password Reminder"
    wshShell.SendKeys "% x"  ' ALT+SPACE+X = windows maximize, must be enabled on hta
                             ' ALT+SPACE+N = windows minimize, must be enabled on hta
                             ' ALT+SPACE+R = windows restore
  ElseIf strArg <= 10 Then
    self.MoveTo 200,50
    window.ResizeTo 900,750
  Else
    self.MoveTo 200,50
    window.ResizeTo 750, 575
  End If
End Sub
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor=Silver>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="80%">
        <p style="PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; margin-top: 0px">
        <font face="Verdana" color="White" style="font-size: 11pt"><strong>Company name</strong></font><br />
        <font face="Verdana" color="Black" size="5"><strong>Password Reset Reminder</strong></font>
        <p>
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" width="50%">
        <img src='\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\logo.jpg' width='451' height='170' style="vertical-align:bottom;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<span id=DataArea></span>

<script language="vbscript">
Set wshNetwork    = reateObject("WScript.Network")
Set wshShell      = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'TableMsgs:
strDaysLeftMsg1  = "We have detected that your password will expire in"
strDaysLeftMsg2  = "day(s) or less."
strPWCriteriaMsg = "<BR>Password criteria:" & _
                   "<BR> - 8 characters or longer" & _
                   "<BR> - At least one alpha, one numeric, and one special character" & _
                   "<BR> - Cannot be an old password" & _
                   "<BR> - Passwords ARE CaSe SeNsItIvE!!!" & _
                   "<BR>"

strArg = 13
arrCommands = Split(objPasswordHTA.commandLine, "-")
If UBound(arrCommands) > 0 Then
  strArg = arrCommands(UBound(arrCommands))
  strArg = strArg * 1
End If
intDaysLeftonPW = strArg

'Generate the HTML for the table
strTableHTML = "<TABLE align=center width=75%>"

If intDaysLeftonPW <= 5 Then
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<font size=5>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR bgcolor=Red><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR><TD><font size=5>" & strDaysLeftMsg1 & "<font color=Red><b> " & intDaysLeftonPW & _
                 "</b></font> " & strDaysLeftMsg2 & "</font>" & _
                 "<BR>" & _
                 "<BR>Please reset your password now to avoid getting locked out or expiring. " & _
                 "The only way to unlock an expired password is to contact Help Desk. " & _
                 "A typical expired password request takes 15-20 minutes.</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR bgcolor=Red><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR><TD>" & strPWCriteriaMsg & "</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & _
                 "<TR><TD><BR><font color=red>To reset password:</font>" & _
                 "<BR>1. Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE" & _
                 "<BR>2. Select " & Chr(34) & "Change a Password..." & Chr(34) & _
                 "<BR>3. Complete the password reset wizard." & _
                 "<BR>" & _
                 "<BR>Caution: There are no grace logons. Expired passwords will not be allowed onto " & _
                 "the network.</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "</font>"
ElseIf intDaysLeftonPW <= 10 Then
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR bgcolor=yellow><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>"
  sTRTableHTML = strTableHTML & _
                 "<TR><TD>" & strDaysLeftMsg1 & "<font color=Red><b> " & intDaysLeftonPW & _
                 "</b></font> " & strDaysLeftMsg2 & "</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR bgcolor=Yellow><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR><TD>" & strPWCriteriaMsg & "</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & _
                 "<TR><TD><BR>To reset password:" & _
                 "<BR>1. Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE" & _
                 "<BR>2. Select " & Chr(34) & "Change a Password..." & Chr(34) & _
                 "<BR>3. Complete the password reset wizard." & _
                 "<BR>" & _
                 "<BR>Tip: Try to avoid resetting passwords on Friday and reset early in " & _
                 "the week. This will give you more opportunities to sign in and get used to the new password " & _
                 "so you do not forget over the weekend.</TD></TR>"
Else
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR bgcolor=Green><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & _
                 "<TR><TD>" & strDaysLeftMsg1 & "<font color=Red><b> " & intDaysLeftonPW & _
                 "</b></font> " & strDaysLeftMsg2 & "</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR bgcolor=Green><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "<TR><TD>" & strPWCriteriaMsg & "</TD></TR>"
  strTableHTML = strTableHTML & _
                 "<TR><TD><BR>Please press CTRL+ALT+DELETE and select Change a Password..." & _
                 "</TD></TR>"
End If

'Add the dynamic HTML to the table/HTA
strTableHTML = strTableHTML & "</TABLE>"
DataArea.InnerHTML = strTableHTML
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vbscript statement mismatch sring failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386289/vbscript-statement-mismatch-sring-failing)

Comment: I have spent 12 hours for the last 3 days on it and I can get it to work just not right, the way the VBscript is now the Mismatch type string error appears for the HTA file which is in the following part:

     strArg = 13

    arrCommands = Split(objPasswordHTA.commandLine, "-")
    If UBound(arrCommands) > 0 then
      strArg = arrCommands(Ubound(arrCommands))
    End If

Comment: In other words I can not correctly state the arguments.

Comment: Making the following change and matching all the numbers appears to be making it work:
strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" & " -14" & intDaysRemaining

Comment: Well that's odd - that's not the command you said you were using on the command line that was working

Answer (score 0):

There is your culprit:

```
strCMD =  "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta" & " -" & intDaysRemaining
'                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You never define `intDaysRemaining` anywhere in your code, so the variable is empty, meaning your commandline looks like this:

```
\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta -
```

Splitting this commandline at `-` gives you an array with an empty string in the last field, which in turn raises the error you observed when you try to multiplicate an empty string with 1.

Demonstration:

```
>>> cmdline = "\\domain\netlogon\PwExpChk\PWReminder.hta -"
>>> a = Split(cmdline, "-")
>>> v = a(UBound(a))
>>> WScript.Echo "_" & v & "_"
__
>>> i = v * 1
Type mismatch (0xD)
```

You would have spotted this right away had you added `Option Explicit` to your VBScript, or at least bothered to echo the commandline in your HTA when debugging (`MsgBox objPasswordHTA.commandLine`).